# Weird getopt =s handling?

Tags: perl

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use locale;

my $prepinac_r = '';
my $array_name = '';

use Getopt::Long;
Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling");
my $result = GetOptions(
"r=s" => \$prepinac_r,
"array-name=s" => \$array_name);

print STDERR "r: $prepinac_r\n";
print STDERR "array_name: $array_name\n";
```

running it:

```
script.pl --array-name=kokos -r=kure
```

output:

```
r: =kure
array_name: kokos
```

What I am doing wrong? What did I miss? Why -r gets "=kure" instead of "kure" ? Please help...

Comment: Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling_override");

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing short for and long form syntax. Short form syntax doesn't use `=` since that would make it less short.

```
"a|all"       => \$opt_all,
"e|execute=s" => \$opt_execute,
```

Short form:

```
-aefoo
-a -efoo
-a -e foo
```

Long form:

```
--all --execute=foo
--all --execute foo
```

Here's an example of the short form you might be familiar with:

```
perl -le'print "Hello World";'
perl -l -e'print "Hello World";'
perl -l -e 'print "Hello World";'
```

Comment: There would be no way to know if `-e=x=x` meant `=x=x` or `x=x` if short form allowed `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Student, you should use double `-` for both switches >>

```
script.pl --array-name=coconut --r=chicken
```

...

```
r: chicken
array_name: coconut
```

Comment: That would prevent bundling, which he specifically enables.

Comment: yes, i would do that too, but i had strict restriction on program arguments

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior you are seeing is because of "bundling".

From [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong#Bundling)

```
Enabling this option will allow single-character options to be bundled. To distinguish bundles from long option names, long options must be introduced with -- and bundles with -
```

So if you are using "bundling", then -

```
--array-name=foo --r=bar # Works
-afoo -rbar              # Also works

--array-name=foo -r=bar  # Does not. as you've already seen
```

It also does not make sense to use bundling unless you are using options that do not require a parameter, and therefor can be "bundled"